# Unable to contact my own XML-RPC server

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does this error mean? I've gotten it occasionally on different computers but I have no idea how to troubleshoot it.

When I got it on my laptop I think it was because I had recently tried changing the computer's own hostname and something was confused. But in this case i don't think it is due to that...

Any advice on where to look?

```
$ roscore
... logging to /u/aleeper/.ros/log/d849da10-6097-11e0-b8d4-003048fd842d/roslaunch-bie-19625.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Unable to contact my own XML-RPC server, this is a highly unusual error and should be reported immediately.
My URI is [http://bie:50000/]
```

Except that isn't the URI, and it changes every time I run roscore ([http://bie:35992/], [http://bie:51667/])

```
$ env| grep ROS_MASTER_URI
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9664/unable-to-contact-my-own-xml-rpc-server/) by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 573 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

The ROS_MASTER_URI isn't relevant to debugging this. This error means that the node is unable to contact itself, i.e. 'bie' does not resolve correctly on the local machine.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1